# How to write a cxf service that uses plain xml over http

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I have developed REST and SOAP services using Apache CXF,was wondering if i could develop a service that takes xml over http and validates using XSD.

Developed a REST service which accepts xml, but wanted a pure XML based service.

is there any example that i can start with ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plain HTTP service with XML validation you can combine the [Jetty HTTP component](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) with the [Validation component](http://camel.apache.org/validation.html).

For example, it could be as simple as:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/myapp/myservice" />
    <to uri="validator:myschema.xsd" />
    <!-- other components -->
</route>
```

And send your XML as the HTTP POST body.